# Using Q.allSettled for a promise chain inside a Loop

Tags: javascript, twitter, q

I'm using the great Q library for promises with an IndexedDB backed in a Chrome App. The issue is Q.allSettled is being called before all the methods in the promise chain are complete.

I have two tables:

1. A search_queries table which has a list of search queries and
2. A tweets table which has a list of tweets.

An auto search of all the search_queries is run like so:

```
var promises = [];

var sq_count = 0;

search_queries.foreach(function (val, index, array) {

  // 1. Search Twitter Asynchronously

  // 2. Then Add them to a tweets table

  // 3. Then update a search queries table


promises.push(
 // Call Twitter API
search_twitter(Q, val)
.then(function(tweets) {
// Add Tweets to tweets table
     return (add_tweets(Q, tweets, val));
})
 // Update number of tweets in search_queries table 
.then(function(search_query){
     // Update counts for search_search query and store it
     return update_search_query_after_search(search_query);
})
.then(function(v){
    console.log("Chain is completed");
)); // Close promise chain


sq_count ++;

if(sq_count ==  search_query_list.length) {
    Q.allSettled(promises)
    .then(function(result) {
         console.log("All Promises Settled);
     }); 
}); // Close foreach loop
```

The number of tweets in the tweets table does not match with the number of tweets that are in the search_query table after running the update_search_query_after_search method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified to

```
var promises = search_queries.map(function(val, index, array) {
    return search_twitter(Q, val).then(function(tweets) {
        return add_tweets(Q, tweets, val);
    }).then(function(search_query) {
        return update_search_query_after_search(search_query);
    }).then(function(v) {
        console.log("Chain is completed");
    });
});
Q.allSettled(promises).then(function(result) {
    console.log("All Promises Settled");
});
```

See if that works for you

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaro. I thought Q.allSettled is firing before all the chains are completed, but I guess it seems like that is less likely than a code bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can state this in a far simpler (and less error-prone) fashion by mapping promises from your source array:

```
//no need to state extra function params if you're not using them
var promises = search_queries.map(function(val){ 
    return search_twitter(Q, val)
        .then(function(tweets) {
            // Add Tweets to tweets table
            return (add_tweets(Q, tweets, val));
        })
        // Update number of tweets in search_queries table 
        .then(function(search_query){
            // Update counts for search_search query and store it
            return update_search_query_after_search(search_query);
        })
        .then(function(v){
            console.log("Chain is completed");
        }); // Close promise chain
});

Q.allSettled(promises)
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("All Promises Settled);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The chains are not getting completed for all my search_queries. I'm trying to understand if its a bug in the code or if Q.allSettled is firing before promise chains are done. I suspect the former.

Comment: @user2738707 As far as I can tell, there's nothing too Q specific here. Why not use plain old [ES6 Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/?redirect_from_locale=it#toc-browser-support)?

Comment: Since I use Angular which uses $q and I'm still using ES5 :). This method is called when a user clicks 'search twitter' for a query as well as by background script to auto-search twitter queries when network is resumed.